# Link has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: .net, angular, gateway, api-gateway, ocelot

I am using Ocelot API gateway in between my front end and back end packages of Angular project. All API calls work fine but Delete call fails. It gives below error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dev-<domain>/api/<appName>/BorrowersPayment/payments/recurring' from origin 'https://dev<link>.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have added below line in ocelot.json.

```
 "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete" ]
```

When my web package makes call to Delete API endpoint via APIGateway, it gives above CORS error. For Get, Post, it works fine.

Comment: Is DELETE set to allowed on your CORS policy on the backend?

Comment: `
services.AddCors(c =>
            {
                c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.AllowAnyHeader().WithMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "PATCH").AllowAnyOrigin());
            });

Comment: Direct call from front to back works fine with Delete but visa Ocelot gateway it gives CORS error

Comment: Restart your server?

Comment: Just now restarted the server. Still same issue